# Passing objects and id as parameters in a function

Tags: javascript

Working on some code and I'm running into an issue I don't know how to fix using javascript.

I have `days` that is a collection of objects that look like:

```
day: 1
a: 10
b: 5
c: 9
d: 6
```

and so forth.

What I want to do is have a function that I can pass `days` and one of the id's for `a, b, c, d` and have it do 'something'. (By something, I'm not sure yet).

I'm just struggling to figure out how to pass the identifier.

```
function returnAll(data, id){
   for (var day in data){
    console.log('On day' + day + ' , ' + id + ' has a value of ' data[day].id)
   }
}
```

Which would ideally put something like this into the console:
    On day 1 , a has a value of ...
    On day 2,  a has a value of ...

When `returnAll(days, a)` is called,  I just can't get the id to link up properly inside of the function. I'll need to call this function for either a, b, c...The `days` can be dynamic so I need a function that operates just on the values of the `id` passed as the parameter.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to access the desired property inside your function:

```
data[day][id]
```

Call it like this:

```
returnAll(days, 'a');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript an object is an associative array. The following should do the trick:

```
data[day][id]
```